# 'GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal' warning in MonoDevelop

Tags: c++, linux, monodevelop

Whenever I run a C++ console program in MonoDevelop IDE in linux, I recieve this warning in the console:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
```

After this message is shown the program runs normally.

So, I want to prevent MonoDevelop from printing this warning. Is there a way to solve the problem or prevent MonoDevelop from printing this message?

Comment: what version of monodevelop is this?

Comment: please upgrade to 5.9 to see if the problem is fixed in the last version